# SaveFileDialog: InvalidOperationException due to "owner" parameter in a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, savefiledialog

Sorry for the long post, but I tried to explain the problem very detailed so that no confusion should arise. The last sentence contains the actual question.

I'm programming a multi-thread application with C#/.NET.

The application consists of a main window, which visualizes data, coming from a pressure sensor. The sensor data is acquired in an own thread.

The data is also logged in an instance of class `ListView`:

[image]

There is the possibility to save the logged data to file on disk via a "Save" button (should open an instance of .NET class `SaveFileDialog`).

This `SaveFileDialog` is also running in an own thread.
Now there's a problem when calling the method `SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()`:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>         Message="Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'tlpMain' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
>         Source="System.Windows.Forms"

The problem arises because the owner (the main window) of the **SaveFileDialog** is running in another thread.

Here's the code, which creates the thread for the SaveFileDialog():

```
private void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread saveFileDialog = new Thread(OpenSaveFileDialog);
    saveFileDialog.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    saveFileDialog.Start();
}
```

Code for method OpenSaveFileDialog():

```
private void OpenSaveFileDialog()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|CSV (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;

    /* Call "ShowDialog" with an owner ("this.Parent") to achieve, so that
     * the parent window is blocked and "unclickable".
     * 
     * Danger of an "InvalidOperationException" because "this.Parent" control
     * is running (was created) in another thread.
     * But "this.Parent" should not be modified by this method call.
     */
    DialogResult pressedButton = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this.Parent);
    ...
```

The **InvalidOperationException** is only thrown/displayed when running the application with Visual Studio's debugger. It is no problem - so far - when running the application "normally".

But I would like to avoid this problem.

I tried to build a wrapper method (SaveFileDialog):

```
private void OpenSaveFileDialog()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    ...
    SaveFileDialog(saveFileDialog, this.Parent);
}
```

Wrapper method :

```
private void SaveFileDialog(SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog, Control owner)
{
    if (owner.InvokeRequired)
        BeginInvoke(new dSaveFileDialog(SaveFileDialog), new object[] { saveFileDialog, owner });
    else
    {
        DialogResult pressedButton = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(owner);
        ...
```

This leads to a `TargetInvocationException` although the `Main()` method is labeled with `[STAThreadAttribute]`:

> InnerException: System.Threading.ThreadStateException
>          Message="Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."
>          Source="System.Windows.Forms"

Does anybody have a clue how to open the `SaveFileDialog` in a way, so that the main window will be blocked ("unclickable") without having the (thread) trouble?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you attempting to do multi-threaded UI?  What is the problem that can't be solved with single-threaded UI?

Comment: The application can handle multiple main windows, so it consists of usually three threads: One thread for "application manager", one for the main window and another one to acquire the data (from a sensor). And now there should be another one to open a "SaveFileDialog".

Comment: The user can't do 3 things at any one time, allow them to do 1 at a time. They will have a much better experience.

Comment: @Benedikt Why do you need a separate thread for the file dialog. Those are invariably run from the UI thread.

Comment: You've made the problem seem very complicated when it's actually quite simple. All UI should be done on the UI thread. This includes the common dialogs. Windows is just enforcing that rule here.

Comment: @ThePower Exactly. My version of this is that you need a one-to-one correspondence between users and user interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run method in separate thread and error with save file dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563271/run-method-in-separate-thread-and-error-with-save-file-dialog)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It was not my attention to use a thread for the **SaveFileDialog**, but showing the dialog with "ShowDialog" a **ThreadStatException** occurs: System.Threading.ThreadStateException was unhandled. Therefore I tried to wrap this into an own thread. I would like to do it how @Cody Gray and @ThePower said it.

Comment: I've no idea why you got this exception, but you do seem to be rather blasé about the use of threads. You could probably run the entire app out of a single thread with the use of a timer.

Comment: I use some external code, which relies on threads. Therefore it's no option to rework this "architecture".

Answer (score 2):

The cross-thread exception you get during debugging is a [Managed Debugging Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx). They are not normally active outside of the debugger. That explains why you do not see when you run the application outside of Visual Studio.

It looks like you have discovered on your own that you simply cannot do anything to a UI element from a thread other than the main UI thread. You use the `ISynchronizeInvoke` methods, namely `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`, to marshal the execution of an operation onto the UI thread so that you can safely access UI elements.

I still see a problem with your code though. In the `OpenSaveFileDialog` method, which is running on the worker thread, you are calling the constructor for `SaveFileDiaglog` which, of course, is a UI element. You just cannot do this. It is worth repeating. You cannot do **anything** to a `Form` or `Control` from a worker thread. That includes calling the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply.

First of all thank you for your quick and helpful responses.

The tip that's not possible

> do anything to a Form or Control from
>   a worker thread

helped me a lot.

I usually not doing GUI programming for Microsoft's Windows and so I'm not so familiar with it.

So I reconsidered the previous source code because I wanted to solve the actual problem
(not doing GUI things from a worker thread) and would like to have a clean and logical code structure.

Therefore I've read in the topics of Window's Component Object Model (COM) and the used threading model:

- What is COM:
  http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx
- Understanding and Using COM Threading Models:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx
- Understanding The COM Single-Threaded Apartment Part 1:
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/CCOMThread.aspx

Now the code looks like this:

The **main window** ("UI thread") is started in `ApartmentState STA`

```
...
ThreadStart threadStart = delegate { RunMainWindow(mainWindow); };
Thread mainWindowThread = new Thread(threadStart);

mainWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
mainWindowThread.Start();
...
```

**"Save" button** event handler (main window):

```
private void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            OpenSaveFileDialog();
}
```

Method "**OpenSaveFileDialog**" (main window):

```
private void OpenSaveFileDialog()
{
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            ...

            DialogResult pressedButton = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            ...
}
```

There is still space for optimizations (for sure), but I'm comfortable with this -  preliminary - result.

So thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this microsoft blogpost: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2011/05/11/10059279.aspx

Just two methods and you are done!